# Add XUbuntu Installation to Manjaro Installation on Same Disk

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, manjaro, xubuntu

*I was struggling whether or not to split this in more questions, but then there'd be no context.*

I have a disk with Manjaro on it. My plan is to add an installation of XUbuntu Core on the same disk. As long as I'm installing and configuring stuff on XUbuntu I want to boot to Manjaro as default. At some point I'd like to remove Manjaro and only XUbuntu should remain on the disk.

Here's the `lsblk` of the Manjaro installation:

```
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1
|                                                                           
|-nvme0n1p1
|    vfat   FAT32       6801-406D                             299,1M     0% /boot/efi
|-nvme0n1p2
|    ext4   1.0         699e74f9-2eee-4040-9479-ffdc18d82c7b  715,8G    18% /
`-nvme0n1p3
     swap   1           d423f454-c0b3-4920-8aef-35fda2d5e3b2                [SWAP]
```

So my first guess is that I have to boot with some live-USB distro and shrink `nvme0n1p2`.

1. Does a `/boot/efi` have to be this big these days? It looks way too big. What would be an optimal size?

Then I'll probably go ahead and install XUbuntu, which hopefully knows what to do here and how to create its partition(s) between `nvme0n1p2` and `nvme0n1p3`.

2. Should XUbuntu have its own `/boot/efi`-partition?
3. Would Manjaro still work now that the swap-partition may have a different location or name on the disk?
4. Would it make sense to look into how I can make XUbuntu use the existing swap-partition for itself, too?
5. How do I convince grub to prioritise Manjaro on both installations even after updates of either system?

And as mentioned already I want to remove Manjaro once I'm happy with XUbuntu. I have no clue what happens if I remove `nvme0n1p1` and `nvme0n1p2`.

6. How do I get rid of Manjaro-partitions leaving a fully working XUbuntu on the disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 The default EFI partition size automatically created by any installer used by Ubuntu, official and unofficial derivatives is 512MB. So no, your current EFI isn't "too big". There isn't any "optimal size" *per se* either because it always depend on the number of OSes simultaneously installed and/or some special cases where it's used for storing other than the OS entries (.efi) alongside those in which case it very likely needs to be bigger, not smaller, obviously.

#2 NO!! Only one ESP (EFI System Partition) per system is required and in case only one per drive is an absolute rule.

#3 Although (x)Ubuntu since a long time ago uses a swapfile by default it'll happily use the existing swap partition => This question is nonsensical.

#4 Cf. #3

#5 You need to set the boot order at UEFI settings > Boot menu, i.e., entirely in the machine's firmware settings and independent from any installed OS. Each Linux OS will have it's own GRUB. (x)Ubuntu now by default has `os-prober` disabled so even when it receives and installs kernel updates it won't ever change the defined boot order in UEFI. Meaning: If you set Manjaro as the default it'll be the default, period.

#6 You need to identify the Manjaro exclusive partitions, typically only root (`/`), and simply remove them by any method from the Xubuntu session. After this Manjaro won't boot, obviously, but Xubuntu should remain intact. Then you can simply change the boot order in UEFI settings to Xubuntu. You may want to run `efibootmgr` in Xubuntu to remove the now non-working Manjaro entry (check help for the necessary parameters; double-check what you're removing). Finally run `sudo update-grub` to update GRUB configuration (it should now boot directly to Xubuntu - single OS - unless otherwise specified).